# How to read an array up till the new line '\n'?

Tags: c, arrays, string, class

So I'm passing an string into this function, where the length of the array is at a default of 50.

I input the string using this

```
void inputDNA(char *dnaSequence)
{
    printf("Enter the sequence.");
    scanf("%s", dnaSequence);
}
```

So I figured /n would be in the last position of the array if its less than 50. So I have this for loop...

```
for(i = 0; i<length || dnaSequence[i] == '\n'; i++)
    {
        switch(dnaSequence[i])
        {
            case 'A': aCount++;
            break;
            case 'a': aCount++;
            break; //do this for g,c,t but for readability I removed them for this post.

            default: 
            {
                printf("Invalid Base %c\n", dnaSequence[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

To read the string and count all a,g,t,c but print out any invalid bases. It does this till it finds the /n or it reaches the end of the array. It does it correctly for the string I entered, but then it just throws in random characters from the rest of the array for the last half and calls them all invalid if they are.

So just to illustrate what I'm talking about, here it is in action. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DB6JB.png)

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory reserved for `dnaSequence` is dirty. `scanf` puts the read characters at the beginning but the end stays the same. You should check for the end of the c-string in the `for` loop.

```
for(i = 0; i<length && dnaSequence[i] != '\n' && dnaSequence[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

EDIT: Tt worth to mention that `scanf` does not read the end-of-line character `\n`. So checking for it is unnecessary.

```
for(i = 0; i < length && dnaSequence[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Comment: Ah okay, that works thanks! Though I'm not sure I get how it works. Why isn't it checking and printing out all the invalid bases till the end of the 50 character array if the for loop doesn't stop until it gets to the end? And the null character is not thrown at the end of the array when declared, it just separates the data thrown in versus the empty spaces in the array?

Comment: @Carson The `\0` character is inserted by `scanf` after it reads all characters (excluding the `\n`) from the input. You have to allocate enough space to store all characters you need plus one (the `\0`). If you want to store 50 characters you need to reserve space for 51 characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your logic in your for statement is bad.  Your for will end when the conditional part of your for loop returns false.

Remember that for's syntax is:
    for(initialization; conditional; increment)

Your conditional should be using an And, not an Or, since i

Try

```
for(i=0; i<length && dnaSequence[i] !='\0'; i++)
```

Comment: agwaraen's answer also applies, your input can be dirty.  For the record, the null terminator character for a C array is \0, not \n.  So if you want to guard the end of your array, try the code that I just edited in.